# How to disable QTableWidget scrolling to selected cell?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

Currently, if the user clicks on a cell that is only partially visible, the window automatically scrolls over so that the cell is fully displayed. Is there any way to stop the table doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scrolling is done by `QAbstractItemView` which call the virtual function `scrollTo` with index the hint `EnsureVisible`. You can't prevent the call, because it is done through a private timer, but you can change what the `scrollTo` function does:

```
void TableWidget::scrollTo(const QModelIndex &index, ScrollHint hint)
{
    if(hint == QAbstractItemView::EnsureVisible)
        return;
    QTableWidget::scrollTo(index, hint);
}
```

And to still be able to scroll to an item manually, you could write another member function that would call `QTableWidget::scrollTo`.

Answer (score 12):

You can easily disable this behavior with:

```
ui->tableWidget->setAutoScroll(false);
```

[alexisdm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894321/alexisdm)'s answer is dealing with another problem. Suppose you are incrementally appending new rows to your table and you want to maintain current vertical scroll position. I am dealing with this second problem and [alexisdm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894321/alexisdm)'s answer seems promising.

Comment: This also works on QTableView tables. Overriding TableWidget::scrollTo() is apparently just an unnecessary, extra step.