# Implementing QTableView sections move properly

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

When I call

```cpp
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);
```

Dragging a section slightly to the right and releasing the mouse button scrolls the table all the way to the left (see
[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc2k8.gif))
Are there any ways to solve this? Qt Version is 6.5.0.

The code is below

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include "MyModel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    auto tableView = new QTableView();
    auto model = new MyModel();
    tableView->setModel(model);
    tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);
    tableView->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

```cpp
// MyModel.cpp
#include "MyModel.h"

MyModel::MyModel(QObject *parent)
        : QAbstractTableModel(parent) {
}

int MyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const {
    return 20;
}

int MyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const {
    return 20;
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QString("%1, %2")
                .arg(index.row() + 1)
                .arg(index.column() + 1);

    return {};
}
```

```cpp
// MyModel.h
#ifndef TEST_MYMODEL_H
#define TEST_MYMODEL_H


#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
};


#endif //TEST_MYMODEL_H
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely the same bug mentioned in here: [Qt stylesheet conflict between QTableView::item and cellWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75927032/qt-stylesheet-conflict-between-qtableviewitem-and-cellwidget/75943506#75943506). It's caused by auto scrolling, but in your case the header view's auto scrolling.

**Solution 1:**

Disable auto scrolling of your header view permanently with this:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setAutoScroll(false);
```

---

**Solution 2:**

Disable auto scrolling of your header view only when the cursor enters it, and enable it back again when it leaves it, by using an **event filter**:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QHeaderView>

class myEventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    myEventFilter (QObject *parent = nullptr) {}

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event) override
    {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::Enter)
        {
            QHeaderView *h = static_cast<QHeaderView*>(obj);

            h->setAutoScroll(false);
        }
        if(event->type() == QEvent::Leave)
        {
            QHeaderView *h = static_cast<QHeaderView*>(obj);

            h->setAutoScroll(true);
        }

        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
};
```

and install it on your header view like this:

```
myEventFilter *filter = new myEventFilter();
tableView->horizontalHeader()->installEventFilter(filter);
```

---

**Solution 3:**

Since the 2 previous solutions seem to disable a needed auto scroll when moving an item to the viewport's edge, here's a workaround that enables that auto scrolling, while getting rid of the unwanted one.

It works by enabling the auto scroll only when the cursor leaves the viewport, and disabling it otherwise.

```
class myEventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    myEventFilter (QObject *parent = nullptr) {}

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event) override
    {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
        {
            QWidget *w = static_cast<QWidget*>(obj);
            qDebug()<<w->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());
            QTableView *h = static_cast<QTableView*>(obj->parent());

            //this condition translates global cursor position to viewport's local position
            //and checks if it left it
            if(w->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x()<=0)
                h->setAutoScroll(true);
            else
                h->setAutoScroll(false);
        }


        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
};
```

and install it on your header view's viewport like this:

```
myEventFilter *filter = new myEventFilter();
tableView->horizontalHeader()->viewport()->installEventFilter(filter);
```

This solution still has one problem, once the auto scroll starts, it does not stop as well, but at least it only gets triggered as normal auto scrolls do, but if you have a large number of columns, it will be a problem.

---

**Solution 4:**

Since auto scroll seems to be a mess in `QTableView`, I got the idea to disable it, and reimplement it myself.

It's very simple. If the cursor is at the edge, scroll the horizontal scroll bar of the table view.

Here's how:

```
class myEventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    myEventFilter (QObject *parent = nullptr) {}
    bool pressed=false;

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event) override
    {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
        {
            pressed = true;
        }
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        {
            pressed = false;
        }

       QHeaderView *h = static_cast<QHeaderView*>(obj->parent());
       QTableView *t = static_cast<QTableView*>(obj->parent()->parent());

       if(h->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x()<=0 && pressed)
       {
            t->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(t->horizontalScrollBar()->value()-1);
       }
       if(h->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x()>=t->viewport()->visibleRegion().boundingRect().width() && pressed)
       {
            t->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(t->horizontalScrollBar()->value()+1);
       }

        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
};
```

and again, install the event filter on your header view's viewport, and disable the auto scrolling.

Here's how:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setAutoScroll(false);

myEventFilter *filter = new myEventFilter();
tableView->horizontalHeader()->viewport()->installEventFilter(filter);
```

The `pressed` boolean is to avoid table viewport from scrolling while you're not trying to, so it only scrolls if you're pressing an item on the header view.

I also added the ability to scroll from left to right.

**Note:**

Since the scrolling speed is too fast, due to the huge number of events going through the `eventFilter`, I came up with a way to control scrolling speed, by scrolling only when custom events are sent, at a rate which can be controlled with a `QTimer`:

Here's how:

```
class myEventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    myEventFilter (QObject *parent = nullptr) {}
    bool pressed= false;
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer();

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event) override
    {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
        {
            pressed = true;
        }
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        {
            pressed = false;
        }
        //check if it's the custom event we sent, I used QEvent::None to avoid causing unwanted effects
        if(event->type() == QEvent::None)
        {
            QHeaderView *h = static_cast<QHeaderView*>(obj->parent());
            QTableView *t = static_cast<QTableView*>(obj->parent()->parent());

            if(h->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x()<=0 && pressed)
            {
                t->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(t->horizontalScrollBar()->value()-1);
            }
            if(h->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x()>=t->viewport()->visibleRegion().boundingRect().width() && pressed)
            {
                t->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(t->horizontalScrollBar()->value()+1);
            }
        }

        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
};
```

and you can use it this way:

```
auto tableView = new QTableView();
auto model = new MyModel();
tableView->setModel(model);
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);

tableView->horizontalHeader()->setAutoScroll(false);
myEventFilter *filter = new myEventFilter(tableView);
QObject::connect(filter->timer,&QTimer::timeout,[=](){QApplication::sendEvent(tableView->horizontalHeader()->viewport(),new QEvent(QEvent::None)); });
//change the duration depending on the speed you want
filter->timer->start(40);


tableView->horizontalHeader()->viewport()->installEventFilter(filter);
tableView->show();
```

---

Here's the [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-112616), the Qt version mentioned in there is 5.15.2, but it seems to affect newer versions as well, I'm on the same version as you are, Qt 6.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

After some improvements to the answer
by Mihoub Abderrahmene Rayene I came up with the following solution:

```cpp
// myEventFilter.h

#include <QObject>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QTimer>

enum MovingState {
    Idle,
    Right,
    Left
};

#define TABLE_SCROLL_OFFSET 0.05

class myEventFilter : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit myEventFilter(QTableView *tableView, QObject *parent = nullptr) : tableView(tableView), QObject(parent) {
        scrollTimer.setInterval(10);
        connect(&scrollTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &myEventFilter::scrollByInterval);
    }

private:
    bool pressed = false;

    MovingState movingState = Idle;

    QTimer scrollTimer;

    QTableView *tableView;

private slots:

    void scrollByInterval() const {
        int scrollStep = 1;
        QScrollBar *scrollbar = tableView->horizontalScrollBar();

        if (movingState == Right)
            scrollbar->setValue(scrollbar->value() + scrollStep);
        else
            scrollbar->setValue(scrollbar->value() - scrollStep);
    };
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) pressed = true;

        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) pressed = false;

        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove && pressed) {
            auto *h = dynamic_cast<QHeaderView *>(obj->parent());

            int cursorPosition = h->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x();
            int tableWidth = tableView->viewport()->visibleRegion().boundingRect().width();

            if (cursorPosition <= tableWidth * TABLE_SCROLL_OFFSET) movingState = Left;
            else if (cursorPosition >= tableWidth * (1 - TABLE_SCROLL_OFFSET)) movingState = Right;
            else movingState = Idle;

            if (movingState != Idle && !scrollTimer.isActive()) scrollTimer.start();
        }
        if ((movingState == Idle || !pressed) && scrollTimer.isActive()) scrollTimer.stop();

        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
};
```

### Usage

```cpp
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setAutoScroll(false);
myEventFilter *filter = new myEventFilter(tableView);
tableView->horizontalHeader()->viewport()->installEventFilter(filter);
```

### Key points

1. I added an offset so that scrolling starts not only outside the window, but in it too (this can be useful in full screen mode)
2. To maintain the same scroll speed, my code uses `QTimer` along with `setInterval`